# Google Map js API set new clusters on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

Here are 2 Array with Latitude and Longitude.

```
const locations1 = [
     { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
     { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
     { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
     { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
     { lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968 },
    ];

const locations2 = [
  { lat: -37.7737, lng: 145.145187 },
  { lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978 },
  { lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119 },
  { lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692 },
  { lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218 },
];
```

which i am trying to load at a time by clearing previous clusters when clicked on button.

Library link as recommended by google: [https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclustererplus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNnBi.png)

***For some some reason, when i click button, it adds new clusters but doesn't clears old one.***
[pre-existing clusters image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNnBi.png)

Here is my code:

```
//on click button clear and load again

  const refresh = document.querySelector('#clearbtn');
  refresh.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
    const clear =   setClusters(markers);   
    clear.clearMarkers();
    const markersNew = setMarkers(locations2);
    setClusters(markersNew);
        
    });

 }
```

Here is full code:

```js
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: {
      lat: -28.024,
      lng: 140.887
    },
  });
  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  const setMarkers = (setmarkers) => {
    return setmarkers.map((location, i) => {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        label: labels[i % labels.length],
      });
    })
  };

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  const setClusters = (setclusters) => {
    return new MarkerClusterer(map, setclusters, {
      imagePath: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m",
    })
  };

  const markers = setMarkers(locations1);

  markerClusterer = setClusters(markers);


  //on click button clear and load again
  const refresh = document.querySelector('#clearbtn');
  refresh.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const clear = setClusters(markers);

    clear.clearMarkers();

    const markersNew = setMarkers(locations2);

    setClusters(markersNew);

  });

}



const locations1 = [{
    lat: -31.56391,
    lng: 147.154312
  },
  {
    lat: -33.718234,
    lng: 150.363181
  },
  {
    lat: -33.727111,
    lng: 150.371124
  },
  {
    lat: -33.848588,
    lng: 151.209834
  },
  {
    lat: -33.851702,
    lng: 151.216968
  },
  {
    lat: -34.671264,
    lng: 150.863657
  },
  {
    lat: -35.304724,
    lng: 148.662905
  },
  {
    lat: -36.817685,
    lng: 175.699196
  },
  {
    lat: -36.828611,
    lng: 175.790222
  },
  {
    lat: -37.75,
    lng: 145.116667
  },
  {
    lat: -37.759859,
    lng: 145.128708
  }
];

const locations2 = [

  {
    lat: -37.7737,
    lng: 145.145187
  },
  {
    lat: -37.774785,
    lng: 145.137978
  },
  {
    lat: -37.819616,
    lng: 144.968119
  },
  {
    lat: -38.330766,
    lng: 144.695692
  },
  {
    lat: -39.927193,
    lng: 175.053218
  },
  {
    lat: -41.330162,
    lng: 174.865694
  },
  {
    lat: -42.734358,
    lng: 147.439506
  },
  {
    lat: -42.734358,
    lng: 147.501315
  },
  {
    lat: -42.735258,
    lng: 147.438
  },
  {
    lat: -43.999792,
    lng: 170.463352
  }
];
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 70%;
}

#clearbtn {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  /* height: 40px; */
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Marker Clustering</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>

  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <a href="#" id="clearbtn">Refresh with new markers</a>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new/second marker clusterer, then removing the markers on it.  Keep a reference to the first marker clusterer you create, that will enable you to remove those markers.

your existing code:

```
//on click button clear and load again

  const refresh = document.querySelector('#clearbtn');
  refresh.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
    const clear =   setClusters(markers);   // creates new/different MarkerClusterer
    clear.clearMarkers();
    const markersNew = setMarkers(locations2);
    setClusters(markersNew);
        
    });

 }
```

instead you can do this:

```
let markerClusterer = null;  // in the global scope.

// ...
const markers = setMarkers(locations1);
 
markerClusterer = setClusters(markers);
  
  //on click button clear and load again
const refresh = document.querySelector('#clearbtn');
  refresh.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    const markersNew = setMarkers(locations2);
    setClusters(markersNew);
        
});
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/81mwhj0g/)

before clicking the "refresh" button:
[image: before clicking "refresh"]

after clicking the "refresh" button:

[image: after clicking "refresh"]

**code snippet:**

```js
let markerClusterer = null;
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 2,
    center: { lat: -28.024, lng: 140.887 },
  });
  // Create an array of alphabetical characters used to label the markers.
  const labels = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  // Add some markers to the map.
  // Note: The code uses the JavaScript Array.prototype.map() method to
  // create an array of markers based on a given "locations" array.
  // The map() method here has nothing to do with the Google Maps API.
  const setMarkers = (setmarkers) => {return setmarkers.map((location, i) => {
    return new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      label: labels[i % labels.length],
    });
  })};
    
  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  const setClusters = (setclusters) => {
    return new MarkerClusterer(map, setclusters, {
    imagePath: 'https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/images/m',
  }) 
    };
  
  const markers = setMarkers(locations1);
  
  markerClusterer = setClusters(markers);

  
  //on click button clear and load again
  const refresh = document.querySelector('#clearbtn');
  refresh.addEventListener("click", () => {
        
    markerClusterer.clearMarkers();
    
    const markersNew = setMarkers(locations2);
    
    setClusters(markersNew);
        
    });

 }



const locations1 = [
  { lat: -31.56391, lng: 147.154312 },
  { lat: -33.718234, lng: 150.363181 },
  { lat: -33.727111, lng: 150.371124 },
  { lat: -33.848588, lng: 151.209834 },
  { lat: -33.851702, lng: 151.216968 },
  { lat: -34.671264, lng: 150.863657 },
  { lat: -35.304724, lng: 148.662905 },
  { lat: -36.817685, lng: 175.699196 },
  { lat: -36.828611, lng: 175.790222 },
  { lat: -37.75, lng: 145.116667 },
  { lat: -37.759859, lng: 145.128708 }
];

const locations2 = [
  
  { lat: -37.7737, lng: 145.145187 },
  { lat: -37.774785, lng: 145.137978 },
  { lat: -37.819616, lng: 144.968119 },
  { lat: -38.330766, lng: 144.695692 },
  { lat: -39.927193, lng: 175.053218 },
  { lat: -41.330162, lng: 174.865694 },
  { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.439506 },
  { lat: -42.734358, lng: 147.501315 },
  { lat: -42.735258, lng: 147.438 },
  { lat: -43.999792, lng: 170.463352 }
];
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 70%;
}

#clearbtn{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  /* height: 40px; */
  background: #3498db;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  margin: 20px 100px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Marker Clustering</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@google/markerclustererplus@4.0.1/dist/markerclustererplus.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
     <a href="#" id="clearbtn">Refresh with new markers</a>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```